# GITHUB Desktop Filename is too long

Tags: github, repository, fatal-error, github-for-windows

I'm trying to upload source code over the github windows app (as long as I can't upload folder over the web app for some reason) But I keep getting the error

```
error: lstat("path/to/file"): Filename too long 
fatal: Unable to process path path/to/file
```

I did add the HOME variable to the enviroment variables and did the following

```
git config --system core.longpaths true
```

But i'm still getting the filename too long error

how to fix it?

Comment: "upload"? upload where? The configuration you set should only apply locally, if you're pushing to a remote perhaps it is the remote that is complaining?

Comment: upload files to my https://github.com repository.  I click "Add Local Repository" in the Github windows app -> then choose the folder -> then click "Commit to master"... it throughs the error.